# Does Riak Support In-Memory Computing

Tags: memory, nosql, riak, in-memory

I am New to Riak. I am planning to implement an In-Memory computing concept. That is Storing the Complete data in the RAM instead of Hard Disk. I have done it with MYSQL using Memory Engine. But I want to try it with the NoSQL. So first I looked at Cassandra, and now I am working on Riak. What I want to know is, Where do the Riak store all the data? In Memory or In Disk?

I googled it for some time and found out that it stores the keys in the memory for low latency. But is there any way to store complete data in the Memory?

If Yes, then how can I setup the Riak to achieve the In-Memory Compatibility. I am doing this for a POC sack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question, but I am afraid there is no qualified person to answer that here, it's too internal. You should try your luck on riak lists.

Comment: @Pentium10: Thanks for the response. What do you meant by "No Qualified Person Here!". Riak was evolved years ago right? I have found Something in the Following URL : "[Riak Memory Storage](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/backends/memory/)". I have to try it. Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: I don't know from the community person who would have easy access to this information. Someone might spot it, but it's a chance.

Comment: @Pentium10 Some of us do hang out here ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach Sorry, I didn't know someone from basho is here, I had this conclusion because there are lots of unanswered questions here regarding Riak, and low quality answers.

Comment: @Pentium10 I was just poking you a bit is all. I try to keep up on them but there's also just some that really are a bit broad / off-topic - I appreciate you mentioning the Riak mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riak has a [configurable backend system](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/planning/backends/).

Riak's default backend is Bitcask. Bitcask persists all data to disk on write, while keeping all keys in memory. The system's file caching is relied on when reading data as to whether a particular value is in memory or not. While [this article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/1/10/riaks-bitcask-a-log-structured-hash-table-for-fast-keyvalue.html) is a bit old, it covers how bitcask works pretty well at the high level.

If you want to simply store everything in memory and not persist to disk, you can configure Riak to use a [memory-only backend](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/backends/memory/). This is done via the `app.config` file in the `riak_kv` section:

```
{riak_kv, [
           %% Storage_backend specifies the Erlang module defining the storage
           %% mechanism that will be used on this node.
           % {storage_backend, riak_kv_bitcask_backend},
           {storage_backend, riak_kv_memory_backend},
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am thinking the same. I can change the storage engine to "Memory". But what if we want to take the daily or weekly backup of the data in the memory to more persistent memory like "Disk"? I have to look into the feasibility with riak in the above scenario.